# Challenge: Laying the Foundation (with Badges!)

Tags: discussion, badges

Since the [mission to earn the vox populi badge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) went pretty well...

### I challenge you to earn a foundational trifecta of badges: Autobiographer, Analytical, and Quorum.

This community is off to a great start. I want to encourage you to continue establishing a solid foundation by focusing on some of the things that make a Stack Exchange site tick:

**You, the users**

While our focus is on content and not about the individual posting a question or answer, individual users are what drive content creation. We do also like to foster a sense of community, and we hope that you all get to know each other through [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4337/salesforce) and [browsing user profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users). To that end, filling out your user profile is a great way to further explain your particular area of Salesforce expertise, or to show off some other aspect of your personality (like if you want to tell people your Twitter handle so they can share photos of their cute dog or what they had for lunch with you). Did you know that you can earn [a badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/9/autobiographer) for filling out *all* the fields of your profile? (Note: your real name and email are never shown on your profile except to moderators and SE staff.)

[image: Autobiographer - bronze badge]

106 of you have earned this badge so far - that's pretty good. If you haven't, will you consider getting to know your fellow Salesforce Stack Exchange users a little better?

**The Stack Exchange model**

This site is a little bit different from most of the [other sites in our network](http://stackexchange.com/sites): There are a lot of users who are joining Stack Exchange for the first time. That means it's really important for those people to learn how Stack Exchange is different from other online communities, and one way to do that is by reading the [FAQ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq). You'll find information about the Stack Exchange model like what reputation is, what types of questions you should and shouldn't ask, why people can edit your posts, and more. Even if you've read the FAQ on another SE site, a refresher might better equip you to help educate others who are new here.

And if you ready *every* section of the FAQ, you'll join the 24 people who have earned [this neat badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical):

[image: Analytical - bronze badge]

(And yes, we do know if you read the whole thing.)

**Conversations about the site itself**

The last piece of this foundation is meta. If you're already here, you probably know [why we have a meta site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), but if you stumbled across this post from the community sidebar, I'll summarize some of the most important parts. [Meta is for](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) questions about which tags to use, defining the scope of the site (on- and off-topic questions), making a case to close or reopen a question, coming up with ideas for promoting the site, reporting bugs, making feature requests, or asking questions to learn more about the Stack Exchange model.  The more people that participate in meta, the more representative the decisions made here will be. It's especially important when a site is young, like this one is, and you have the opportunity to shape it into the exact community you want it to be.

So if you've never posted to meta before, don't be shy; jump right in and maybe you'll earn the [Quorum badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/badges/67/quorum):

[image: Quorum - bronze badge]

(Thanks to the 35 of you who already have! If you see someone new here on meta, and they have something constructive and useful to say, vote on their post to help them earn this badge, too!)

**Let's see how many people can earn these badges over the next week.**

Keep up the good work, and good luck!

Comment: +1 These challenges are a great way to get people involved :) And damn you I've got 2 out the 3, so now I've got to find a reason for a decent meta post!

Comment: Not sure how to get the Analytical badge? I have read all FAQ sections by clicking the links in the sidebar. I would have thought that should do it.

Comment: @Anup You did earn it on the main site. Because meta has it's own FAQ, you have to read that one in order to earn the badge on meta. :) (And if you didn't see the badge on the main site before, you should see it now - badges aren't awarded instantaneously, it takes a little while for our system to notice and award them.)